# Identify the curve from the sample points

Tags: geometry

I am writing a script which will identify the patterns drawn on the touch-pad of the laptop. I have generated all the points where user moved his finger over the touch-pad using [synclient](http://linux.die.net/man/1/synclient). 
 
Now i have the points and i want to identify the pattern from these points.
 
For simplicity i have restricted the patterns to alphabets[A-Z], numbers and simple curves like circle, semi-circle, vertical and horizontal lines.

So, how to identify the curve from the set of points?

Comment: The first step is to normalize the inputs. For instance, you could put a rectangle around the letter or shape, then use an affine transform to map it to a 1x1 square. Then you can match the normalized input against some patterns. MMSE is a reasonable comparison method, I guess. Many machine learning methods, such as neural networks can be used as well. You need to provide your inputs as well as the patterns to get a better answer. I can't see a direct relation between your question and Mathematica, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an easy task. Unless you have many months (or maybe even years) to work on this, I recommend that you use an existing library for handwriting recognition. There is an open source one at [this CodeProject page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/363596/Library-for-online-handwriting-recognition-system), Windows has the "ink analysis" API, and there are probably others. I strongly recommend that you search around before attempting this yourself.